# Android Socket to Server, Server reports "Connection Reset" error

Tags: java, android, sockets

am developing an Android Application for Email System, and the application needs to connect server (written by my partner).
My cellphone use wifi generated by my PC, when I try to login,the server just reports the "Connection reset"error for a few times in 10 seconds.

```
Client Login IP:59.71.68.237 Server host:Iris   Time:2015.06.13 at 09:04:36
java.net.SocketException:Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputSteamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
    at com.mailService.emsp.tempEMSP.run(tempEMSP.java:42)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I debug in Android,and I find out that the code stops after executing

```
client = new Socket(ServerInfo.sockethost, ServerInfo.socketport);
```

and the server reports error just after that.

Here is the client code.

```
public class Login extends Activity {

private Intent intent = null;
private EditText account = null; //Account
private EditText passwpord = null; //password
private Button login = null; // login
private TextView register = null; // register

private String useraccount = null;
private String userpassword = null;

private Dialog m_Dialog = null; // dialog

private Socket client; //client socket
private BufferedReader reader;
private PrintWriter writer;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    intent = this.getIntent();

    account = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.login_account);
    passwpord = (EditText) this.findViewById(R.id.login_password);
    login = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    register = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.login_register);

    register.setClickable(true);
    //login button event
    login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            useraccount = account.getText().toString();
            userpassword = account.getText().toString();

            //judge whether the account is null
            if (Regex.isEmpty(useraccount)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill in account！",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            // judge whether the account meets email form
            else if (Regex.isEmail(useraccount)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "account form is wrong！",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            // judge whether password is null
            else if (Regex.isEmpty(userpassword)) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill in the password！",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Client：Connecting");
                m_Dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Login.this, "Hint", "Login...",true);

                // create a new thread
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    int flag = 0;           
                    int mark = 0;

                    // based on the custom protocol
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            // create a new socket
                            System.out.println("new Socket('', 6666);");
                            //This is where the code stops
                            client = new Socket(ServerInfo.sockethost,  ServerInfo.socketport);
                            System.out.println("Socket 'client' created.");

                            String command = null;
                            System.out.println("new reader.");
                            // IO reader and writer
                            reader = new BufferedReader(
                                    new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
                            System.out.println("new writer.");
                            writer = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
                            // Client:login
                            writer.println("login");

                            while ((command = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(command);
                                String cmd = stk.nextToken();
                                System.out.println("cmd:" + cmd);
                                if (cmd.equals("user")) {
                                    writer.println(useraccount);
                                    System.out
                                            .println("writer.println('useraccount');");
                                } else if (cmd.equals("pass")) {
                                    writer.println(userpassword);
                                    System.out
                                            .println("writer.println('userpassword');");
                                } else if (cmd.equals("inexist")) {
                                    writer.println(useraccount);
                                    System.out
                                            .println("inexist,  writer.println('username');");
                                } else if (cmd.equals("error")) {
                                    writer.println(useraccount);
                                    System.out
                                            .println("error,  writer.println('username');");
                                } else if (cmd.equals("loginok")) {
                                    System.out.println("case 'loginok'");
                                    mark = 1;
                                    System.out.println("========mark = "
                                            + mark);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            System.out.println("Login succeed!，flag=0");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            flag = 1; // Login fail
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                if (client != null)
                                    client.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        m_Handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (flag == 0) {
                                    ServerInfo.username = useraccount;
                                    ServerInfo.password = userpassword;
                                    intent.setClass(Login.this,
                                            MainActivity.class);
                                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                                    bundle.putString("username",
                                            useraccount);
                                    bundle.putString("password",
                                            userpassword);
                                    intent.putExtras(bundle);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    Login.this.finish();
                                    System.out
                                            .println("Client: Login succeed!");
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Login succeed!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                } else {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                            "Login fail!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                            .show();
                                }
                            }
                        });
                        m_Dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

When I execute client code separately from the application, it just works fine!

What is the problem ? Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here, but there is certainly something seriously wrong with a server that reports the same error several times. The problem is at that end. Clearly he is continuing to use the socket after end of stream has occurred.

Comment: Have you set the proper permission to access the network? Is there any exception in the logs?

Comment: Yes.I have.The log in "logcat" shows that the coded just stop after new Socket(). It reports exception after it had tried for a long time to get connection with the server.【connection time out】

Comment: You can't get a 'connection reset' on a connection that never existed because of a connect timeout. Make up your mind. What is your question again?